# Android Built-in Popoup Sender

Tags: android, email, bluetooth, popup, built-in

I would like to know if there is already any built-in popup for android, giving some options to send file.
Via Bluetooth/Email and maybe other options if they exist.

Any default popup already done to be used? Or I have to make my own?

I searched at google and didn't got good results.

Thanks alot in advance ;)

Comment: Yes, maybe thats what I am looking for.

Comment: lol.. I was searching with the bad keywords, just writed share intent at google and found what I was looking for at the first link . Don't know if I should put here the link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a [Share Intent](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html). There's a good tutorial on it [here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/) as well, in case you find the official document from the previous link lacking.